# Printing an object to screen in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, output, firebase-realtime-database, getelementbyid

I am using firebase and JavaScript and I have managed to retrieve some data from the database but only by console.logging it.

When I do console.log(snapshot.val().users); I get:

```
Object {0h6giHjZIVS3Bd2azuar3vDwDqH2: Object, 9QqsaC9aNBXUVcPAfTGXd2UWWyJ3: Object, E1VV06umwFdLWUkNkXuEFiIk94F3: Object, E9i702ShW2S33zfsj7m4FVg8tW92: Object, GH39ayyIFkaBrEe2JpsXWtPyZRG2: Object}
```

but when i try to print it to the screen by doing this

```
document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = snapshot.val().users;
```

I just get `[object Object]`

How can I get the objects appearing or actual attributes of the objects?

Comment: You need to write code to display the properties in whatever format you want.  Look at Handlebars.js.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for you, that Object is pretty mean, but try this:

```
document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val().users);
```

Comment: that worked of sorts, but how can I hit a specific attribute of an object?

Comment: snapshot.val().users["propertyName"] or snapshot.val().users.propertyName. If it is not a Object then you don't need JSON.stringify. You should be able to check what properties an object has in the console by logging it out.